# webview + html5 video is not working

Tags: cocoa, html, webview, html5-video

I'm developing an application that has to display some html content that contains an html5 video (no flash/silverlight plugins). The html and the video are playing fine in safari, but when displayed inside the webview in my application i get a black box where the video should be. But the video seems to be playing, because if i click fullscreen, the video goes fullscreen and is correclty displayed, and also the audio is present, in fullscreen and non fullscreen mode. It seems like the video is played behind the page.

Maybe i'm missing something as a newbe?

does anyone has an html5 video correctly displayed inside a webview on a mac os x 10.6?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the webview?

Comment: I'm having the same problem under OSX 10.8.2 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536897/cocoa-webview-html5-video-fullscreen-not-working
Did you ever find a solution?