# Cocoa webview - html5 video fullscreen not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, webkit, html5-video

I'm trying to build an osx cocoa application with an integrated webkit webview to display a web page.

On the webpage are html5 video elements which the user should be able to play in fullscreen.
But fullscreen just shows a black screen on mountain lion (10.8.2) audio is still playing but on osx lion it worked, is this a bug or did I miss something.

Minimum Sample:

Steps:

Create a cocoa app add a webview connect the property "web" and add the webkit framework

Code:

**`#AppDelegate.h`**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *web;
@end
```

**`#AppDelegate.m`**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  NSString *html = @"<html><body><video src=\"http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4\" controls></body></html>";
  [[self.web mainFrame] loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
@end
```

## **FIXED IN OSX 10.8.3:**

**Problem seems to be fixed in OSX 10.8.3 fullscreen is working now, even without sandboxing as it did prior to OSX 10.8.2**

Comment: I can confirm this bug and that it worked until 10.8.1, so there has been a change in the latest update.

Comment: A filed a but report with apple, let's wait and see

Comment: Excellent, I did as well. Filling duplicates is one of the few ways to give the bug priority.

Comment: I just did the same. Anyway I'm happy that it's not my code that crash with HTML5 videos :)

Comment: Finally after a long time Apple responded: It is a duplicate of #12313594, my bug id is #12412325. But no words about a workaround or any other advice. Does someone know what do to next?

Comment: Is it possible to sandbox your app? A workaround seems to be to enable sandboxing, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup a project with the exact code you posted. This did indeed fail for me, and only showed a black screen in full-screen mode.

However this seems to be a sandboxing issue with WebKit. After sandboxing the app full screen worked as expected. (Using 10.8.2)

The app was sandbox without any additional permissions needed to make this work:

[image]

Comment: It works for the demo code, but I need to allow outgoing connections for my app, if I enable "Allow Outgoing Connections" I'm back to the black full screen, accepted as answer, because it solves the posted problem. But I hope someone knows a solution which allows outgoing connections

Answer (score -2):

could u try this code, hope it will work with u.. this works on iphone and i guess it will work on osx

header file

```
UIWebView *webView;
```

Implement file

```
NSString *html = @"<html><body><video src=\"http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4\" controls></body></html>";

webView =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14, 57, 670, 675)];
        [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: UIWebView is not available on osx